# Typescript - "... is not a function or its return value is not iterable"

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have this helper function:

```
export function to(promise: Promise<any>) {
  return promise
    .then((data: any) => [null, data])
    .catch((err: Error) => [err, null]);
}
```

This function (in theory) should help me catch errors while using `await` in functions. for example:

```
const [err, data] = await to(validate(card));
```

The problem is that on runtime, I get the following error:

> to is not a function or its return value is not iterable

While the expected return signature should be `Promise<[Error, null]> Promise<[null, Error]>`, it looks like returns (again, in theory, because it actually fails): `Promise<any[] | Error[]>`:

[image: function to]

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume your `validate` call should be a call to `to`, right?

Comment: @ShamPooSham you're right. My mistake. I have updated my question

Comment: Can you put together an small example where this happens?

Comment: I got exactly the same error in pure Javascript due to a branch in the called function which mistakenly returned a single element instead of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by duck typing, TypeScript is not able to guess the return type correctly from the expressions.

You can type it explicit:

```
function to(promise: Promise<any>): Promise<[Error, any]> {
    return promise
        .then((data: any) => [null, data] as [Error, any])
        .catch((err: Error) => [err, null] as [Error, any]);
}
```